# how to fix the issue of CategoricalIndex column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with chicago crime data and want to aggregated count of top 5 crimes for each region/community area. However, my code works but I got unwanted index and CategoricalIndex type column in dataframe columns which stop me to access particular columns for further data manipulation.

**what I did**:

```
crimes_2012 = pd.read_csv('Chicago_Crimes_2012_to_2017.csv', sep=',', error_bad_lines=False)
df=crimes_2012[['Primary Type', 'Location Description', 'Community Area']]
crime_catg = df.groupby(['Community Name', 'Primary Type'])['Primary Type'].count().unstack()
crime_catg = crime_catg[['THEFT','BATTERY', 'CRIMINAL DAMAGE', 'NARCOTICS', 'ASSAULT']]
crime_catg = crime_catg.dropna()
```

here is my current output that needs to be improved:

[image]

**here is my attempt**:

when I tried below code, I still didn't get new index and index name displayed strange in output dataframe. why? how to fix this? any idea? Thanks

[image]

even when I tried to reindex dataframe it didn't get new index after all.

```
crime_catg.reindex(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

any idea to fix this issue? any thought?

Comment: IIUC, you need reset_index. df.groupby(['Community Name', 'Primary Type'])['Primary Type'].count().unstack().reset_index()

Comment: @Vaishali I tried that of course but I got this error: `TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category`. why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this.

1) Keep the `CategoricalIndex` type and the use `.add_categories` method to update valid categories eg to fix your `.reindex` problem:

```
crime_catg.columns = crime_catg.columns.add_categories(['Community Name'])
```

2) Cast as `pandas.Index`:

```
crime_catg.columns = pd.Index(list(crime_catg.columns))
```

Comment: why I have this error `TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category`, any idea?

Comment: What is the name of the column you are trying to add into the main DataFrame?

Comment: it's my mistake, thanks for your answer, accept  it

Comment: so remember that categories are case sensitive, so you have to add them in quite precisely... but you're wanting to do something along the lines of  `crime_catg.columns = crime_catg.columns.add_categories(['Community Name', 'new_crime_1', 'new_crime2'])` .... etc

Comment: Also , if you don't require the benefits of `CategoricalIndex`, there's always option 2), just cast it to a normal index.

Comment: one more question, when I do aggregate the total crime for each region from 2012-2017, how can I count annual crime count for each region? I know this is not part of this question, could you give me quick insight about it?

Comment: Difficult to give you an exact reproducible answer without sample data, but generally you would groupby both 'region' and 'year', something like: `crimes_2012.groupby(['Region', 'Year']).count()` or maybe with `pandas.crosstab` like: `pd.crosstab(crimes_2012.Region, crimes_2012.Year)`

Comment: Been looking for this fix! Made my day! Thank you!